# Do I need to refine my reference to the video?

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I have used video.js for several videos on two previous projects. The projects were cross browser and work fine.

On project 3 I set up the video reference in a floating div like so...

I get the following error from Firefox on loading the page into the browser...

**Media resource tio4.mp4 could not be decoded. tio4.php
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.**

I attempt to play the video subsequently with...
videojs("example_video_1").play();

but (of course) it does not play.

Swapping tio4.mp4 with a video from a previous project I have no problems.
Running tio4.mp4 (The video that gives the "could not be coded" error) in Movie Maker shows the video running fine.

Do I need a refinement in my video reference? What else?

Comment: Could you provide a demo link (jsfiddle, jsbin etc)?  Or at least a snippet of code.  It would seem to me that you may have a bad encoding if the same video/videojs code can play different videos.

Answer (score 0):

The original video (The one giving me the problems) was formatted in an obscure tool.

I put it in Movie Maker and tried saving it which made no difference. I then cut a tiny piece off the Movie and saved it as a "clip" which worked on this one and a subsequent one!